# How to address high level tags (html, body) in a Vue/Vite app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I need, in a Vue/Vite bootstrapped application, to dynamically set a class on "upper" DOM elements such as `<html>` or `<body>`.

The application is constrained to a dynamic block (`<div id="app"></div>` by default).

Is there a way to address, with Vue mechanisms, the "upper" DOM structure?

My workaround will be to fall back on standard JS and use constructions such as `document.getElementById("html-id").classList.add('MyClass')` but wanted to make sure that Vue does not address this.

Comment: Vue is managing everything inside the div with id=app. Maybe the browser title gets changed during navigation or something, but it's not the norm to update anything outside the app. The real solution is to make the entire website the vue app. Native JavaScript to update HTML elements manually is also acceptable, but this depends entirely on your project and if it's for hobby/work/study/school.